# System Logs out when unused for some time instead of going into lock screen

Tags: unity, login, login-screen, lock-screen

I have switched to **XFCE4** some days back from **Unity**, but now i again switched to Unity. From that time onwards I am facing following problem.

My system **logs out automatically** when unused for some time, say 2 minutes (according to My **Brightness And Lock** Settings) and goes to **Switch user** screen instead of **lock screen**

How to tackle this problem ?